# Only break lines at specific delimiter

Tags: line-breaking

Given the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\linefoo{%
\vline\hspace{0.1cm}%
}

\begin{document}

\linefoo Lorem ipsum dolor sit \linefoo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus \linefoo non varius enim. Vestibulum aliquet, \linefoo odio ut gravida
rutrum, nisl \linefoo tellus fermentum ex, eget imperdiet \linefoo velit nibh sit amet
elit. \linefoo Curabitur id semper odio, quis \linefoo interdum sapien. Vestibulum
faucibus magna \linefoo quis nulla dapibus fringilla. Donec \linefoo massa erat,
interdum vitae urna \linefoo ac, ornare vulputate felis. Proin \linefoo ut odio
eget nunc bibendum \linefoo elementum. Etiam accumsan tellus at \linefoo eros maximus
semper. Vestibulum iaculis \linefoo velit et tellus condimentum posuere. \linefoo Sed
enim lorem, tempor quis \linefoo dolor ac, volutpat volutpat elit. \linefoo Cras
tincidunt ultricies faucibus. Donec \linefoo sem lorem, ullamcorper nec volutpat
\linefoo ac, rhoncus nec turpis. Etiam \linefoo vel efficitur risus. Praesent at
\linefoo ipsum pharetra lectus convallis vehicula \linefoo quis non purus.

\end{document}
```

I want to make sure that LaTeX will break the lines, so that every line must start with the contents of `\linefoo` (in the real problem I have, the definition of `\linefoo` is different). Note that not every `\linefoo` should force a line break, as `\linefoo`'s appearing in the middle of a line is fine.

I have tried to define `\linefoo` as either

```
\newcommand\linefoo{%
\penalty-9999%
\vline\hspace{0.1cm}%
}
```

or

```
\newcommand\linefoo{%
\penalty-10000%
\vline\hspace{0.1cm}%
}
```

but the first one doesn't change when the lines are broken and the second will always break a line before a `\linefoo`.

How can I achieve this, preferably by only changing the definition of `\linefoo`?

---

Here's an example: Given the input

```
\linefoo foo bar \linefoo baz qux \linefoo foo bar \linefoo baz
qux \linefoo foo bar
```

and LaTeX normally breaks the lines as

```
| foo bar | baz qux | foo
bar | baz qux | foo bar
```

I want it to break the lines as

```
| foo bar | baz qux
| foo bar | baz qux
| foo bar
```

instead and not as

```
| foo bar
| baz qux
| foo bar
| baz qux
| foo bar
```

Comment: \\ or `\newline` instead of `\penalty-9999`?

Comment: @Ruben This doesn't do what I want, see the example in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\linefoo{%
  \ifhmode\ifinner\unskip\egroup\space\fi\fi
  \hfil\penalty0\hfilneg
  \vline\nobreak\hspace{0.1cm}%
  \hbox\bgroup\def\par{\unskip\egroup\par}%
}

\begin{document}


\linefoo Lorem ipsum dolor sit \linefoo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus \linefoo non varius enim. Vestibulum aliquet, \linefoo odio ut gravida rutrum, nisl \linefoo tellus fermentum ex, eget imperdiet \linefoo velit nibh sit amet elit. \linefoo Curabitur id semper odio, quis \linefoo interdum sapien. Vestibulum faucibus magna \linefoo quis nulla dapibus fringilla. Donec \linefoo massa erat, interdum vitae urna \linefoo ac, ornare vulputate felis. Proin \linefoo ut odio eget nunc bibendum \linefoo elementum. Etiam accumsan tellus at \linefoo eros maximus semper. Vestibulum iaculis \linefoo velit et tellus condimentum posuere. \linefoo Sed enim lorem, tempor quis \linefoo dolor ac, volutpat volutpat elit. \linefoo Cras tincidunt ultricies faucibus. Donec \linefoo sem lorem, ullamcorper nec volutpat \linefoo ac, rhoncus nec turpis. Etiam \linefoo vel efficitur risus. Praesent at \linefoo ipsum pharetra lectus convallis vehicula \linefoo quis non purus.

\end{document}
```

Comment: note the definition would be simpler and safer if you marked this up as a command taking the content rather than as a delimiter so `\zz{first text bit} \zz{second text bit} ...`

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how it works?

Comment: @Tyilo it is putting each phrase in an `\mbox` so it doesn't break (which is why it would be easier if the markup took the phrase as an argument} without any definition `\mbox{phrase one} \mbox{phrase two}...` will only break between mboxes

Comment: Good ol’ “Mathematical Reviews Exercise” solution: +1!

Comment: @GuM I leave originality to the duck drawers

Answer (score 0):

Some low level trickery:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\linefoo{\leavevmode\linebreak[0]\vline}

\newenvironment{foo}
 {\endlinechar=32 \obeyspaces
  \begingroup\lccode`~=32 \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\nobreakspace
  \hyphenpenalty10000
  \raggedright\par
 }
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
\linefoo Lorem ipsum dolor sit \linefoo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus \linefoo non varius enim. Vestibulum aliquet, \linefoo odio ut gravida
rutrum, nisl \linefoo tellus fermentum ex, eget imperdiet \linefoo velit nibh sit amet
elit. \linefoo Curabitur id semper odio, quis \linefoo interdum sapien. Vestibulum
faucibus magna \linefoo quis nulla dapibus fringilla. Donec \linefoo massa erat,
interdum vitae urna \linefoo ac, ornare vulputate felis. Proin \linefoo ut odio
eget nunc bibendum \linefoo elementum. Etiam accumsan tellus at \linefoo eros maximus
semper. Vestibulum iaculis \linefoo velit et tellus condimentum posuere. \linefoo Sed
enim lorem, tempor quis \linefoo dolor ac, volutpat volutpat elit. \linefoo Cras
tincidunt ultricies faucibus. Donec \linefoo sem lorem, ullamcorper nec volutpat
\linefoo ac, rhoncus nec turpis. Etiam \linefoo vel efficitur risus. Praesent at
\linefoo ipsum pharetra lectus convallis vehicula \linefoo quis non purus.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will report an “Overfull `\hbox`” if too long a line occurs between two consecutive `\linefoo` commands: I’m not sure if this is a bug or a feature.  But what happens if the source contains several spaces in a row looks almost surely like a bug!  You’re losing “french spacing”, too…

Answer (score -1):

￼

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand\linefoo{% 
\ifhmode\ifinner\unskip\egroup\space\fi\fi \hfil\penalty0\hfilneg 
\vline\nobreak\hspace{0.1cm}% 
\hbox\bgroup\def\par{\unskip\egroup\par}% 
 } 
\begin{document} 
\linefoo Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
\linefoo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus 
\linefoo non varius enim. Vestibulum aliquet, 
\linefoo odio ut gravida rutrum, nisl 
\linefoo tellus fermentum ex, eget imperdiet 
\linefoo velit nibh sit amet elit. 
\linefoo Curabitur id semper odio, quis 
\linefoo interdum sapien. Vestibulum faucibus magna 
\linefoo quis nulla dapibus fringilla. Donec 
\linefoo massa erat, interdum vitae urna 
\linefoo ac, ornare vulputate felis. Proin 
\linefoo ut odio eget nunc bibendum 
\linefoo elementum. Etiam accumsan tellus at
\linefoo eros maximus semper. Vestibulum iaculis 
\linefoo velit et tellus condimentum posuere. 
\linefoo Sed enim lorem, tempor quis 
\linefoo dolor ac, volutpat volutpat elit. 
\linefoo Cras tincidunt ultricies faucibus. Donec 
\linefoo sem lorem, ullamcorper nec volutpat 
\linefoo ac, rhoncus nec turpis. Etiam 
\linefoo vel efficitur risus. Praesent at 
\linefoo ipsum pharetra lectus convallis vehicula 
\linefoo quis non purus. 
\end{document}
```

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brXUj.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brXUj.jpg): http://￼`enter code here`
[image]
\documentclass{article} \newcommand\linefoo{% \ifhmode\ifinner\unskip\egroup\space\fi\fi \hfil\penalty0\hfilneg \vline\nobreak\hspace{0.1cm}% \hbox\bgroup\def\par{\unskip\egroup\par}% } \begin{document} \linefoo Lorem ipsum dolor sit \linefoo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus \linefoo non varius enim. Vestibulum aliquet, \linefoo odio ut gravida rutrum, nisl \linefoo tellus fermentum ex, eget imperdiet \linefoo velit nibh sit amet elit. \linefoo Curabitur id semper odio, quis \linefoo interdum sapien. Vestibulum faucibus magna \linefoo quis nulla dapibus fringilla. Donec \linefoo massa erat, interdum vitae urna \linefoo ac, ornare vulputate felis. Proin \linefoo ut odio eget nunc bibendum \linefoo elementum. Etiam accumsan tellus at \linefoo eros maximus semper. Vestibulum iaculis \linefoo velit et tellus condimentum posuere. \linefoo Sed enim lorem, tempor quis \linefoo dolor ac, volutpat volutpat elit. \linefoo Cras tincidunt ultricies faucibus. Donec \linefoo sem lorem, ullamcorper nec volutpat \linefoo ac, rhoncus nec turpis. Etiam \linefoo vel efficitur risus. Praesent at \linefoo ipsum pharetra lectus convallis vehicula \linefoo quis non purus. \end{document}

```
enter code
```

- **List item**

Comment: i took the liberty and formatted your first code chunk, for second you should do yourself (you need to move each code line start for four spaces right). i didn't check if your answer has any sense.

Comment: in what way is this different from the other answer, you appear to have simply copied the code from there and reposted?